# Django-rest-frame work get details of oneToOne Filed

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am building userprofile functionality,below are the details of  Models, ModelSerializer and ModelViewSet.

When I send GET request to UserProfile, I am getting only fields that are in UserProfile Model.But I also wants to get firstname, lastname, email etc which are exist in User model.

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='userprofile');
    state= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    add1= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    add2= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    postalcode= models.IntegerField()
    country= models.CharField(max_length=200)


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
      model = UserProfile
      fields = ('state','city','country')



class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
      serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

     def get_queryset(self):
       if self.action == 'list':
          return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
       return self.queryset
```

Please let me know how can I get the details of OneToOneField from userProfile model.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user serializer and add it to the user profile serializer and  in the fields.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:      
      model = User
      fields = '__all__'

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:      
      model = UserProfile
      fields = ('state','city','country','user')
```